# Disabling page numbering bottom of page

Tags: r, markdown

Newbie question here. I seem to have some trouble changing the page numbering. I want it in the header, instead of the bottom of the page. I got the header working, but I have been deleting and changing code to no avail in order to delete the page numbering at the bottom.

\pagestyle{header}, works but removes some of the information in the header itself.

\pagenumbering{gobble}, nope.

It will probably be a very simple solution, I am just a tad confused :)

I looked at some other topics, but the `fancyhdr` website just gives more questions

```
---    
...
    date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
    tags: [nothing]
    output: pdf_document
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{lipsum}
      - \usepackage{multicol}
      - \usepackage{xcolor}
      - \usepackage{framed}
      - \usepackage{booktabs}
      - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
      - \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
      - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      - \pagestyle{fancy}
      - \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
      - \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage}

    ---

    \pagenumbering{gobble}

    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \small
    \tableofcontents
    \normalsize
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Could you post  a small compilable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of gobbling the page number I would use \fancyfoot{} to remove the footer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
       \usepackage{multicol}
       \usepackage{xcolor}
       \usepackage{framed}
       \usepackage{booktabs}
       \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
       \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
       \usepackage{fancyhdr}
       \pagestyle{fancy}
       \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
       \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage}
       \fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}


    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \small
    \tableofcontents
    \normalsize
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo Ups! Thanks for notifying me!